# Multi User Core Data w/ XPC

Tags: objective-c, core-data, launchd, xpc, nsxpcconnection

Howdie,

This is my first post, so if this has been answered somewhere please forgive me (I did search).

Problem:
I have a Cocoa app that needs to share a single Core Data database among multiple user accounts on the system.

Idea:
I would create a daemon to handle requests from the users (to cross user privilege boundaries) to save/retrieve the data from Core Data. Create a shared Managed Object Context that is used in the application and pass that MOC to the daemon through NSXPCConnection. The daemon will have a fully realized Core Data Stack. I can then set the MOC that was created in the app to be a child of the MOC that was created by the daemon. Hit save and I'm done?

Question:
Would this even work? Is this just a dumb idea? What are the other solutions? NSManagedObjectContext conforms to the NSCoder protocol, but in order to use it with XPC I have to subclass it and make it conform to the NSSecureCoding protocol? Would I also just need to make sure my ManagedObject subclasses conform to NSSecureCoder protocol to use with NSXPConnection? I suppose I can ditch the context all together and just send the managed objects.

I'm assuming NSXPCConnection copys objects instead of using pointers? Is this correct?
Also, I'd probably have to keep performance in mind as the objects are coded/ decoded as fully realized objects and not faulted. Is this correct?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: This question seems a little overly broad. You might have more success if you narrow it down a bit, ask more direct questions and show us some code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it works. ;-)

But there are some special problems you have to deal with. To make a long story short: I think that it would be better to use an [incremental store](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSIncrementalStore_Class/Reference/NSIncrementalStore.html) doing this. But its documentation is close to poor.

We implemented something like this for syncing. And we [have to](http://objective-cloud.com) implement this for networking. (That is, what you want to do.) Here are the problems:

A. 
Moving around the context won't help. The context contains a subset of the store objects. Which one is in the context is random to the app programmer. (Inserted and changed objects will live there, but not changed, not inserted objects can be there and can go away.)

B.
You can of course move around the store. Since it is on the hard disk, this would be easier, if you have access to that location, where it is stored. You can use an XPC service for that.

Doing so has the problem that you do not know, what one user changed. You only get the whole store. In contrast an incremental store knows the specific changes through the [save request](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSSaveChangesRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

C. 
"Different users" means that you have conflicts. This is "unnatural" to Core Data. Is is a graph modeller and being that, it is not "connection based". It opens a document, owns it, changes it, stores it, and closes it. As every document it is typically not owned by two or more apps (including two running instances of one app) at one time. There is no real good mechanism for working on a store simultaneously. So you have to handle that yourself. It is probably easier to handle that on the level of the incremental store than on a level build on top of it.

What you want to do is not that easy, if you do not make assumptions you can make in your special case. (For example having a locking mechanism on a higher level.)

My 0,05 $.